# Visiting Romania and Bulgaria on a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, eastern-europe

I have been granted multiple entry Schengen Visa from 12th Sep to 28th Oct(47 days) with 32 days as duration of stay. Since, Romania and Bulgaria allow visa-free entrance on a valid schengen visa, can I spend my initial 30-32 days in schengen area and the remaining 15 days in Romania and Bulgaria?

Comment: Romania and Bulgaria are not in Schengen. So your stay in these countries will not count for stay in schengen area. You will be stamped out when you exit schengen border.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Bulgaria](http://www.mfa.bg/en/pages/109/index.html) and [Romania](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) uniliterally accept holders of Schengen visas to visit their countries without requiring an additional visa:

> Visa-free regime for holders of Schengen visas for a stay of up to 90
>   days
>
> On 25 January 2012 the Council of Ministers of the Republic of
>   Bulgaria adopted a decision according to which by the date of
>   Bulgaria’s accession to the Schengen area, our country will
>   unilaterally apply a visa-free system for holders of valid Schengen
>   visas. They will have the right to enter and reside in the Republic of
>   Bulgaria for a period of no more than three months in any six-month
>   period from the date of the first entry, without needing to have a
>   Bulgarian short-stay visa. The decision entered into force on
>   31.01.2012.

---

> V. Do I need a visa?
>
> ​1. YES
>
> ...
>
> 2. NO
>
> ...
>
> ​The holders of Schengen visas with two or multiple entries, national
>   visas or residence permits issued by Schengen Member States.
>
> Attention! The number of entries as well as the right of stay
>   established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted.
>   The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the
>   right of stay granted as per the visas/residence permits issued by the
>   Schengen Member States. The holders of permanent residence permits
>   issued by the UK or Ireland. The right of stay on the territory of
>   Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per such
>   residence permits.

Comment: Thanks @downhand. I was just wondering if I exhaust my 32 days in schengen area, will it also exhaust my 'right to stay' as per Schengen visa while entering Romania?

Comment: It depends on how you interpret these sentences, but if you take them literally, in case your visa is not exhausted yet, and you're not planning to go back to Schengen countries, you should be fine staying until the end of your visa's validity period in those two countries. Still, I wouldn't rely on someone's comments on the internet for that, and contact the embassy, since a misunderstanding will be very costly to you.

Comment: @downhand Embassies seldom provide advice on questions like this and have no authority over border guards in this respect so even doing that might not offer any guarantees.